# images do not display in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

am trying to store images in storage folder in Laravel 8 and at the same time fetch that image and displays it in browser, unfortunately, the images get saved but do not display

here is my file

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;


class PostsController extends Controller
{
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
public function create(){
    return view('posts.create');
}
public function store(){
    $data = request()->validate([
        'caption' => 'required',
        'image' => ['required','image']
    ]);
$imagePath = request('image')->store('uploads','public');
$image = Image::make(public_path("{C:\xampp\htdocs\app\storage\app\public\uploads\
   {$imagePath}"))->fit(1000,1000);
$image->save();
    dd($imagePath);
auth()->user()->posts()->create([
        'caption' => $data['caption'],
        'image'=>$imagePath,
    ]);

return redirect('/profile/'. auth()->user()->id);
}
public function show(\App\Models\Post $post){
    return view('posts.show', compact('post'));
}
}
```

any help guys

Comment: I would strongly refrain from using absolute paths. The helper methods such as `public_path` is made to let you navigate laravel's folder relatively.

Comment: You'll need to show the route file(web.php) and the view. Also space between your methods would be more readable.

Comment: You need to create symlink your path `storage\app\public\uploads` to `public/uploads` if are you on linux but it seems you are using windows you can google some solutions I guess windows supports it too. If you rather avoid all this work then you can simply use `Image::make(request()->file('image'))->fit(1000,1000)->save(public_path() . '\uploads\' . request()->file('image')->getClientOriginalName())`

Comment: hello, i have used $image = Image::make(request()->file('image'))->fit(1000,1000)->save(public_path().'\uploads'.request()->file('image')->getClientOriginalName());
            $image->save();  , it does not through any error but the image doesnt display